# Keeping pre-cooked asparagus crisp

Tags: salad

I would like to pre-blanch some asparagus to dress and serve later as a salad. Will it stay crisp?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you shock the asparagus in iced water after you blanch it. The reason some/most vegetables become limp after blanching is because they have been heated and continue to cook on residual heat. An ice bath, or just running it under cold tap water will stop the cooking process and preserve the crispness.

Comment: That's good advise Adrian, I will do that

Comment: This is good advice, I would suggest an ice bath is much more effective than cold tap water.